# How can I retrieve table constraints using Databricks REST API at the schema level?

Tags: rest, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog, databricks-rest-api

I would like to know if someone faces the same issue as I do. If so, how did you solve it?
I need to get the DDL at the schema level in Databricks so I can use the REST API ->
GET `/API/2.1/unity-catalog/tables`. However, it does not return the table constraints, although it is listed in the API [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/api/gcp/workspace/tables/list)

The response includes all the metadata except the table constraints.

Is there something that I might have missed?

I am using the below input parameters:

[{"key":"catalog_name","value":"demo","equals":true},{"key":"schema_name","value":"marts","equals":true},
{"key":"include_delta_metadata","value":"ture"}]

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same thing and was told by Databricks that using [list](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/tables/list) does not return these constraints, although using [get](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/tables/get) for a single table does. I have tested this and can confirm experiencing the same thing. Their documentation for list does suggest these constraints should be returned, but that is wrong.

Additionally, if you're using the [Databricks python SDK](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-sdk/), it does not return the constraints. I'm not sure if these issues are related, but I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sdk-py/issues/435) to detail that problem as well.